# Stack memory allocation

Tags: c++

It is being said that local variable will be allocated and deallocated automatically when function ends in C/C++.

According to my understanding, when having been deallocated, the value held by local variable also be destroyed!!! Please correct me if i'm wrong

Consider following code:

```
void doSomething(int** num)
{
  int a = 10;
  *num = &a;
} // end of function and a will be destroyed

void main()
{
  int* number;
  doSomething(&number);
  cout << *number << endl;  // print 10 ???
}
```

Could anybody clarify for me?

Comment: Ugh, please don't do `void main()`.

Comment: It prints `10` only because the value hasn't been overwritten by something else yet. It's only because of luck that it appears to work.

Comment: @Josh:  That wont help, especially if OP is running in Debug mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. your cout may or may NOT print 10. It will invoke undefined behavior.

---

To make a bit more of a note, try running the following code under your compiler with no optimizations enabled.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void doSomething(int** num)
{
    int a = 10;
    *num = &a;
}

void doSomethingElse() {
    int x = 20;
}

int main()
{
    int* number;
    doSomething(&number);
    doSomethingElse();
    cout << *number << endl; // This will probably print 20!
}
```

Comment: I think user538042 gets 10, that's why the post was made.

Comment: +1, though the `cout` may in fact print 10. Or it may print -34528719849, format the hard drive or summon the nasal demons.

Comment: I would bet that `cout << *number << endl;` always prints 10 if it's called immediately after `doSomething(&number);` and no multithreading involved.

Comment: @a1ex07: nope. There are optimizing compilers, interrupts and OS with its kernel threads.

Comment: Great! Thanks for all for yours answers. The answer #3 is correct indeed. Main function prints 10 as I expected but if I insert another cout << "something" << endl before cout << *number << endl, interesting thing happened. Main function doesn't print 10 but arbitrary number because now portion of that stack has been overriden. Thank you guys

Comment: +1, but: it **may** print 10. It may even print 10 for twenty years, and then fail one a single vital machine. That's the problem with "undefined behavior", it is usually not undefined enough.  I took the liberty to change your wording to that effect.

Comment: @ruslk: If it's optimized somehow and not using stack, then you are right. In other cases, if it's a stack associated with task or thread (not created for signal handling), it won't be affected. Moving stack pointer to a different address doesn't destroy data by itself.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, the integer `a` is on the stack.  You are returning the address of that variable to the main program.  The value at that address location after the call is undefined. It is possible in some situations that it could print 10 if that portion of the stack was not overwritten (but you certainly would not want to rely on it).

Answer (score 1):

The content of the memory isn't actually destroyed. 
For this case, num will point to a location which isn't being allocated for any variable, but it will hold it's content, which was set to 10.

Answer (score 1):

The memory being pointed to has been released back to the system.  That means that it will hold whatever value it had until the system assigns that block of memory to another variable and it gets overridden with a value.

Local variables are released when they go out of scope.  If you are trying to return a value using an out parameter to a function:

```
void doSomething(int** num)
{
  int* a = new int;
  *a = 10;
  *num = a;
}

int main()
{
  int* number = 0;
  doSomething(&number);
  std::cout << *number << std::endl;  // print 10 ???
  if (number) delete number;
}
```

Though, for something this simple, you are better off just doing this:

```
int doSomething()
{
  return 10;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << doSomething() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Zac: "Bleurgh!" directed at the first example, for my part. Is it really such a great idea to inculcate newbies with the wonders of allocating memory and relying on the caller to release it again? :) To the OP -- read Effective C++, I seem to remember it having a good item on this particular point. Plus it's just a good book anyway.

Comment: @Zac, interesting, you check before delete but not before de-referencing!

Comment: @Stuart:  It was more to answer his question.  He cannot allocate an item on the stack and pass that item's memory location back and have it be valid.  Hence the reason for the second example.

Comment: @Nim:  That was more for demonstration purposes.  He can see the value (valid or not) of what is in memory.

Comment: @Zac: If you're showing him how to do something, you might as well show him the *right* way to do it up-front though. Not the way that will come back and bite him in the butt later. Nim's point is also a good one, since deleting a null pointer is a no-op.

Comment: @Stuart:  I did ... the second example is what he should be doing for something this simple.  As for the check, it is true for the standard memory manager.  If you use a custom memory manager, that is not always the case.  Its more habit than anything else.  And I completely agree that the Meyer's and Sutter books are great places for the OP to look.